# How to send session cookies in a fetch request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, session-cookies

In python I wrote some code that allows me to fetch data by sending the session cookies:

```py
import requests


url = "https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2021/segments/0/leagues/1662510081?view=mRoster"
print(url)
r = requests.get(url,
cookies={'swid': '{A1cFeg47WrVdsREQZNAo}',
        'espn_s2': 'AWDB51sqnG8dsc3wfdsffsd'})
d = r.json()
d
```

I wanted to implement this in javascript so I wrote:

```js
  let leagueId = 1662510081;
  let endpoint = "mRoster";
  let url =
    "https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2021/segments/0/leagues/" +
    leagueId +
    "?view=" +
    endpoint;

  console.log(url);

  let playerList = [];

  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    });
```

How can I implement the cookies in the fetch request? I tried set-cookies in the headers but that didn't end up working.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question tags *nodejs*, I'm assuming you are using `node-fetch`;

Apparently, there isn't any explicit way to send cookies, except using the `headers` method. So, you can use this code.

```js
let fetch = require('node-fetch'); // or import fetch from 'node-fetch';
let leagueId = 1662510081;
let endpoint = "mRoster";
let url =
  "https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/ffl/seasons/2021/segments/0/leagues/" +
  leagueId +
  "?view=" +
  endpoint;
console.log(url);

let playerList = [];

fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        cookie: "test=test"
    }
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }); // node-fetch
```

Also, `browser/vanillaJS` method:

```js
...
  fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include'
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }); // browser/vanillaJS
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Where can I go in the chrome developer tools to see what's being transferred over?